# Dockerfile which won't run

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm making a Dockerfile to implement a server appliance.

I believed my file to be complete, but on implementing it I am returned an error;

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 22: /opt/author/application/bin/start-ppliance.sh: Permission denied
/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 22: exec: /opt/author/application/bin/start-appliance.sh: cannot execute: Permission denied
```

In the Dockerfile itself, I run the following;

```
RUN  chmod -R 0750 /opt/author/
RUN  chown -R USER1:USER1   /opt/author/
```

As well as;

```
USER USER1
```

In the Dockerfile itself the last line is;

```
CMD ["/opt/author/application/bin/start-appliance.sh", "run"]
```

I'm not clear why this error occurs, as the file is inside the container and is owned by the default user.

Comment: Use the `{}` button in the editor (with a block selected), or four-space indents, to code-format multi-line blocks.

Comment: Could you post the entire Dockerfile?

Comment: For debugging, adding a couple RUN commands with an `ls -al /opt/author/application/bin/`, `echo $(whoami)` might also help figure out what's going on

Answer (score 1):

As you already know, this usually happens when your file doesn't have the execute bit set, though your `chmod 750` should, in theory, handle this. One way to debug if that's actually the issue would simply be to pass in a different `CMD` at `docker run` time (e.g. `docker run -it <image> sh`) and check the script's permissions with `ls -l`. More often than not, not having execute bit set is the culprit.

If it's not that, I'd recommend clarifying the question with the full Dockerfile just in case something like a `VOLUME` directive may be discarding the effects of the `RUN` you're using.

Comment: When I enter the container \w docker run -u container_name -ti --entrypoint sh repo/container:ve.rs.io.n and review the operating file it has the x bit set.

The implementation section of the Dockerfile is as follows: